# Getting "chmod(): Operation not permitted" on "composer update"

Tags: permissions, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

When I run 'composer update' I get this error:

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files


  [ErrorException]                  
  chmod(): Operation not permitted
```

*It works just fine with sudo, but then I have to reset the owner & permissions, Which is really annoying...
**I also tried to reset the owner of ~/.composer to www-data with 777, no effect.
***I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + Apache/2.4.18 & php7.0.26

---

Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

`chmod` will only work without `sudo` if the owner of the file is the same as the one running the `composer update` command.

The problem is that the error message doesn't tell you which file it's trying to `chmod`.

This depends on the project.

**Running the command in verbose mode** will give you more details:

```
composer update -v
```

In my case, it gave me a stack trace, showing which file called `chmod()`, and the line number.
However, it didn't give me the path of the file passed to `chmod()`.
I had to **add a simple `echo`** right before the call to `chmod()` (without forgetting to remove it afterwards).

Once you know which file/folder is responsible for the error message, **change its owner with `chown`**.

In my case (Magento 2.3), the culprit was the `bin/magento` file, which needs to be owned by the user running the `composer` commands.

Comment: Changing `bin/magento` owner helped