# chmod(): Operation not permitted error while Magento2 extension installation using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2, ubuntu-19.04

I installed magento 2.3 in localhost (Ubuntu 19.04). and changed the ownership & permissions of install directory using the command

```
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magentoProject
 sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/magentoProject
```

and i included user to www-data group.

I installed composer globally. And whenever i run the composer command inside my project directory am getting the error as below.

[image]

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated in your question you have ...

- changed the owner and group to `www-data` for your project
- added your user `midhun` to the `www-data` group
- gave the project-directory group-write permissions `chmod 775`

... but you're wondering why those permissions aren't granted.

Your new group membership on ubuntu isn't applied until you **log out** and **log back in**. Therefore you're effectively not yet a member of the `www-data` group!

Another option is to use `su` to switch into a subshell with your user like this:

```
su -m -l - "$(whoami)"
```

This will apply the new group ownership right away.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the ownership of `bin/magento` file to the user you are using for `composer`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56563434/4482269